# When would yum be of use to an Ubuntu user?

Tags: package-management, yum

My understanding is that yum, and the rpm system,  is only useful on distributions such as Red Hat, Fedora and CentOS. I thought that Ubuntu, as a Debian based system, had no use for yum.

So I was surprised to [find yum in the (universe section of) the official Ubuntu repositories](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/yum/).

When would yum be of use to an Ubuntu user?

Answer (score 3):

Yum is for RPM packages.   RPM is not the preferred installation method in Ubuntu.   The equivalent to Yum would be APT and dpkg.  Yum is not a preferred way to update an Ubuntu system.

To install it, you can do so from USC, or from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install yum
```

I don't think you would have a use for it, since there are equivalent Commands in Ubuntu.  See the [Table of Equivalent Commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromLinux/RedHatEnterpriseLinuxAndFedora)

I would think that it can be used as a backup, if for some reason normal command won't work.

Comment: +1 The idea to use it as a backup is a good one--I have needed to get some software while my `dpkg` cache was amok.

Comment: Does it actually work as a backup?

Comment: @fluteflute It acts as another way to get software if apt is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 3):

The primary use case for `yum` in Ubuntu is if a third-party application has its own `yum` repository, and no `apt` repository. Then it will *sometimes* work to install `yum`, enable the vendor/project repository for that software, and install the software.

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to create come types of LXC Containers, for example, those based on CentOS.