# Beginner installing rpm package

Tags: edubuntu

On latest version Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I have tried this :

```
sudo apt-get install yum
```

Then it says :

```
sudo password for user
```

And nothing gonna happen , if hit enter 3 times it says 3x incorrect attempt.

I'm beginner to Linux

Comment: The proposed duplicate question explains that nothing is displayed when you enter your password. But why are you trying to install an rpm?  Most packages are available as `.deb` somewhere and these are preferred on Debian based distributions such as Ubuntu.  `.rpm` is for Red Hat based linux.

Comment: @WarrenHill  I have  JDK8 i586/x86_64 .rpm and netbeans-8.0-linux.sh

Comment: Then perhaps this is the question you are looking for: [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](http://askubuntu.com/q/56104/107450)

Comment: @WarrenHill  no I'm beginner on Linux so it's haven't yum want to install yum how to install yum

Comment: See [When would yum be of use to an Ubuntu user?](http://askubuntu.com/q/161437/107450). I've never used it myself.

Comment: @WarrenHill  so we can't install .rpm and .sh packages?

Comment: It's possible, but not easy for a beginner. Edit your question to tell us exactly what you would like to install and we can probably tell you an easier way to do it.

Comment: @WarrenHill I want install jdk8-8u5-linux-x64.rpm and NetBeans-8.0-linux.sh on ubuntu 14.04 lts

Comment: @user73898 Why?! Install the .tar.gz version of jdk8* That does not depend on an installer. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: @Rinzwind it's doesn't need by terminal?

Comment: Sorry but you make no sense at all. Of course it needs a terminal?! I said: it does not depend on apt-get or yum so you do not need a programm to install it.

Comment: @Rinzwind ok thank you so tell me how to install .gz and .sh packages .thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use version for other Linux releases if you can avoid it. rpm is for Redhat. On the [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) page there is also a version ending in .tar.gz. Use that.

Installtion is the same as unpacking the tar.gz file (it does not have an installation process and all you need to do is untar the file and move the files to a location you like).

---

Installation:

- download the file from the link
- `cd /opt/`
- `sudo tar xvfz /tmp/jdk* .

(change /tmp/ to where you download your files).

and you will find the files under `/opt/jdk1.8.0_05/`

Setting it up and configuring parameters is up to you.