# Is it possible to rpm and yum package manager in Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, rpm, yum

I saw **rpm** and **yum** packages in the official repos!
Will installing it mean that I will be able to install ***.rpm*** apps from Fedora repos??

See the pictures attached
[`apt search rpm` results showing and describing yum package manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrJfP.png)

[`apt search rpm` results showing and describing rpm package manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5txlm.png)

Comment: No you did not. You saw a tool named that that is basically "alien". A packge converter.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please, provide text outputs rather than screenshots. It helps finding the question and improves formatting. Thanks

Comment: do you mean `cross-compiling`  ?

Answer (score 1):

> Will installing it mean that I will be able to install .rpm apps from Fedora repos??

**No**. I believe these package are in the repository for serving other purposes. For `rpm` it is required by `alien` package for converting . And for `yum` I believe that's included for working in a `chroot` environment as hinted by [this launchpad answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yum/+question/240933).

And there will lots of issues if you try to use a rpm repository in Ubuntu. You need a working rpm based system to use a rpm repository. Ubuntu is based on Debian and uses debian packages. Trying to install even a simplest `dirdiff` rpm  throws errors complaining lacking of most basic `libc.so.6` library. It's also not recognizing `/bin/sh` and `ldconfig`, although those are available in the system.

Here is the output of the trial

```
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
warning: Downloads/dirdiff-2.1-163.6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3dbdc284: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/sh is needed by dirdiff-2.1-163.6.x86_64
    /sbin/ldconfig is needed by dirdiff-2.1-163.6.x86_64
    libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by dirdiff-2.1-163.6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by dirdiff-2.1-163.6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) is needed by dirdiff-2.1-163.6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) is needed by dirdiff-2.1-163.6.x86_64
    tcl is needed by dirdiff-2.1-163.6.x86_64
    tk is needed by dirdiff-2.1-163.6.x86_64
```

This indicates that, A whole system should be built based on rpm packages, otherwise it's not possible to just install rpm. However, you can install rpm packages by first converting those into debian packages.

Check these question

- [How do I install and manage RPMs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2988/how-do-i-install-and-manage-rpms)
- This answer of the question [When would yum be of use to an Ubuntu user?](https://askubuntu.com/a/166897/61218) about Yums purpose in Ubuntu repository